# Python class run once

Tags: python, class, random

*(sorry for my english)*

Guys, my class in Python runs once

```
import csv, random
class myPassword:
        azlower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        azupper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
        simbol = "!@#$%*"

        passw = random.sample(range(9), 2)
        passw = ''.join(map(str, passw))
        passw += random.choice(simbol)
        passw += random.choice(azupper)
        passw += random.choice(vowel)
        passw += random.choice(azlower)
        passw += random.choice(simbol)
        passr = random.sample(range(9), 3)
        passw += ''.join(map(str, passr))

for i in range (0,2):
        print (myPassword.passw)
```

This code runs the same password in every `for`.
How to run the class again?
Tkx!

Comment: don't use a class? Use a function... return `passw`  in your function.

Comment: That code should not be in a class.

Comment: The code in the first indentation only runs once. This part is used to define the structure of a class so it should only run once. `myPassword.passw` is just a static class variable.  You may want to `def` a method or just simply use a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a class here is not the thing to do. You want to use a method:

```
def myPassword():
        azlower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        azupper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
        simbol = "!@#$%*"

        passw = random.sample(range(9), 2)
        passw = ''.join(map(str, passw))
        passw += random.choice(simbol)
        passw += random.choice(azupper)
        passw += random.choice(vowel)
        passw += random.choice(azlower)
        passw += random.choice(simbol)
        passr = random.sample(range(9), 3)
        passw += ''.join(map(str, passr))
        return passw
for i in range (2):
    print (myPassword())
```

Comment: Thanks!! Working as well